# Kubernetes config map for Spring boot application.properties

Tags: kubernetes

I have many spring boot application which i want to deploy in Kubernetes cluster. I came across an option to use file based config map. I am not clear on this. I am looking for to import the entire application.properties for each application and should be able to refer that in the corresponding service. There could be chances for the same keys in different application.properties. Not sure how to load the complete application.properties file by application and just refer from corresponding service.

Also, How can i secure this application.proerties so that only the corresponding application can refer this?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use Spring Config https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/ ?

Comment: Spring config is a good choice, but trying to learn kubernetes config

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes has a special place for that kind of data - [Secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/).

That type of objects is visible only in Namespace where it's created so you can run your applications in different namespaces and each application will able to use only secrets in its namespace.

Also, you can [encrypt your secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/encrypt-data/).

So, first of all, you need to create a secret with your data:

```
kubectl create secret generic <secret-name> --from-file=<file-you-want-to-create-as-a-secret>
```

You can also include several files into one secret. In a [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#creating-a-secret-using-kubectl-create-secret), you can find an example.

Now, you can [mount your secrets](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#secret-management) into a Spark app to the executor and, if you want, to the driver:

```
--conf spark.kubernetes.driver.secrets.<secret-name>=<path/in/container>
--conf spark.kubernetes.executor.secrets.<secret-name>=/etc/secrets
```

After that, you can use your secrets in the application as regular files.

Comment: OP is not asking about secrets

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it for my Spring Boot application.
You can see two variables - one is from environment and another from the file `env-variables.txt` which can be renamed to your `application.properties`

Documentation is here [Create ConfigMaps from files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#create-configmaps-from-files)

My properties are in this file:

```
$ cat env-variables.txt
FAREWELL_FROM_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE=Bon Voyage
```

In Spring Boot, I access it as usual

```
@Value("${FAREWELL_FROM_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE:default}")
String farewell;

@GetMapping("")
public String alive() {
    return greeting + " I am alive, yay!" + " but now I must leave, so " + farewell;
}


$ kubectl create configmap  re-config --from-env-file=env-variables.txt
configmap/re-config created

$ k set env deploy regular-encourager --from=configmap/re-config
deployment.apps/regular-encourager env updated
```

Check the deployment descriptor is correct. Note that I have 2 variables:

```
$ k describe deployment regular-encourager

    Environment:
      GREETING_FROM_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE:  HOLA!
      FAREWELL_FROM_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE:  <set to the key 'FAREWELL_FROM_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE' of config map 're-config'>  Optional: false
    Mounts:
```

Now do the usual. Maven build, Docker build, then docker tag, then docker push to the registry.
Delete pod so the deployment will recreate it.
You can test it like this and see it working :)!

```
$ k exec -it regular-encourager-5547cd5dc7-mxwfn -- bash
root@regular-encourager-5547cd5dc7-mxwfn:/app# curl localhost:8080
HOLA! I am alive, yay! but now I must leave, so Bon Voyage
```